# Python script fails when trying to concatenate

Tags: python, concatenation, pynput

So I'm trying to make a keylogger as a little starter project to help me learn more about programming. I am using pynput to detect keyboard input and I want to keep adding the characters to a variable called `line`. The script I am about to show works when I put `line += str2` outside the function, but not in (The `str` variables were put there to debug this exact thing.)

Here is the code:

```
import msvcrt, datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

date = str(datetime.date.today())
line = "a"
str1 = "1"
str2 = "2"

#Saves given data to a dated text file.
def saveToFile(data):
    file = open("keylog_{}.txt" .format(date), "a+")
    file.write(str(data))
    file.close()

def on_press(key):
    line += str2
    print(line)

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=None) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me figure out why this happens.

Comment: Can you add a traceback of the error? It looks like your variables are not global.

Comment: Does this give an error or just not work?

Comment: add `global line` before `line += key` in the `on_press` fucntion, to indicate that you're trying to modify `line` global variable and it'll work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with variable scope.  `line` in your `on_press` method is not the same variable as `line` up above.  If you want to do something like that, you need to tell it to use the global scope variable:

```
def on_press(key):
    global line
    line += key
    print(line)
```

Comment: Dang, i was just adding that to my answer! Beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

You arent doing anything with the key thats sent into your on_press function. Did you mean this:

```
def on_press(key):
    global line
    line += key
    print(line)
```

also line is going to be unassigned in your example, to do a global you have to use the keyword global or make a class/closure for state retention.